# test input type file in jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

How i  can simply make unit testing for the value of input type file :

```
<input required type="file" class="form-control blue-border" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" data-testid="file" />
```

I tryed

```
descripe('ex....',()=>{
     test('ex.....',()=>{
     const file=screen.getByTestId('file')
     expect(file.value='myfile.png').toContain(/(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png)$/i)
})
})
```

but i have error :
InvalidStateError: This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
expect(file.value).toMatch(/(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png)$/i)
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer but the error i had it's not because The Matcher it's  because i can't set value for the input type file because security reason